# Custom Validation in asp.net for string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am having a textbox and a submit button. I want apply Custom validation to the TextBox for string values. How can I achieve that? Somebody please help me

Comment: Tagged with both languages because it was not specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RegularExpressionValidator` for this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]$" ControlToValidate="idOfYourTextBox"
    ErrorMessage="Only letters are allowed, no digits!" />
```

Replace the `ValidationExpression` with an expression of your pleasure. In this case it restricts the inputs to letters.

Comment: I need to use custom validation. How to do that? please help

Comment: How do you validate? Maybe its easier to use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you're using Web Forms, you could do this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="myCustomValidator"
     ControlToValidate="YourControlID"
     Display="Static"
     ErrorMessage="Your error message!"
     OnServerValidate="ServerValidation"
     runat="server"/>
```

Then, in the code-behind, add this:

```
void ServerValidation(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args) { ... }
```

or, in VB.NET:

```
Sub ServerValidation(source As Object, args As ServerValidateEventArgs)
```

setting `args.IsValid` to `true` or `false` accordingly.

Now, there is one more thing you'll need to do, either:

1. Call `Validate()` in the `Click` handler for the `submit` button, or;
2. Set the `ValidationGroup` properties of the control you want to validate **and** the `submit` button to be the same.

Comment: UserName<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" />
            <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvUserName" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" OnServerValidate="Custom_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Only letters allowed,digit is not allowed" /> This is my aspx code. In aspx.cs page I have written protected void Custom_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    { }          . I dont what should write inside curly braces

Comment: @arshed ... um ... okay. So first, why wasn't that included in the question? You've already gone down the right road. But second, what are you trying to say with that comment?

Comment: A `RegularExpressionValidator` would be totally sufficient (in regards to your error message).

Comment: @arshed, I don't know what you should write either. But do your validation, and if it fails, set `args.IsValid = false;`

Comment: @arshed, what in the world does that mean? You're not explaining yourself when you comment. Consider my position - I know nothing about your application, your needs, or even the information you already know. Help me out here.